# SharePoint Online, Add a webpart to wiki page

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online, feature, sandbox-solution, wiki-pages

I need to add a web part to an existing wiki page [Type="GhostableInLibrary"], when a feature is activated.

I have tried a combination of both IgnoreIfAlreadyExists and ReplaceContent properties in the file element of module. But no success.

What is the way to achieve the above requirement.